# How do I do a backward join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I completely understand how to get ids of photos of a user by doing:

```
User.where(id: 1).joins(:photos).pluck('photos.id')
```

but I don't understand how to get the users of a list of photos except by doing:

```
User.where(id: photos.pluck(:user_id))
```

Is there another Rails way?

Comment: I would like to thank sawa for corrections

Comment: It's not necessary to thank people for editing. It's something we do to try to make the content more readable, as a service to the community as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following:

```
User.joins(:photos).merge(photos).uniq
```

And if you need the list of user ids, do this:

```
photos.pluck('users_id').uniq
```

Comment: yep... And you need list of users or user_ids?

Comment: sometimes one sometimes another, you can supplement the answer

Comment: Try this `User.joins(:photos).merge(photos)`. It will produce one sql query too.

Comment: it works, but still returns not unique objects
but if we add .uniq it will works correct with SELECT DISTINCT and class is ActiveRecord::Relation, awesome
Can you update major answer and i will mark it as solution